# run r*ply like function in parallel

Tags: r, plyr

I need to replicate a function 1000 times and would like to take advantage of multiple cores. It appears that the r*ply functions in plyr can't take advantage of the parallel integration. How can I use another of the plyr functions to replicate a function?

Edit for further clarification:
I would prefer that the results of the function be an array, so I was using raply.

Comment: The package `foreach` makes this very easy, but you can also use `mclapply()` or `parLapply()` in the `parallel` package.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but using `dplyr` rather than `plyr` can achieve huge performance boost, even without parallelization.

Comment: @Andrie. Thanks for the tip on using foreach directly. Worked like a charm.